# Reason for finding partial order of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

In a recent algorithms course we had to form a condensation graph and compute its reflexive-transitive closure to get a partial order. But it was never really explained why we would want to do that in a graph. I understand the gist of a condensation graph in that it highlights the strongly connected components, but what does the partial order give us that the original graph did not?

The algorithm implemented went like this:

1. Find strongly connected components (I used Tarjan's algorithm)
2. Create condensation graph for the SCCs
3. Form reflexive-transitive closure of adjacency matrix (I used Warshall's algorithm)

Doing that forms the partial order, but.... what advantage does finding the partial order give us?

Answer (score 0):

Like any other data structure or algorithm, advantages are there only if it's properties are needed :-)

Result of procedure you described is structure that can be used to (easily) answer questions like:

- For two nodes `x, y`. Is it `x<=y` and/or `y<=x`, or neither?
- For a node `x`, find all nodes `a` that are `a<=x`, or `x<=a`?

These properties can be used to answer other questions about initial graph (DAG). Like, if adding edge `x->y` will produce a cycle. That can be checked by intersecting set `A`, of `a<=x`, and set `B` of `y<=b`. If `A` intersection `B` is not empty than edge `x->y` creates a cycle.

Structure also can be used to simpler implement algorithms that use graph to describes other dependencies. E.g. `x->y` means that result of calculation `x` is used for calculation `y`. If calculation `x` is changed than all calculations `a` where `x<=a` should be re-evaluated or flagged 'dirty' or result of `x` removed from a cache.